# How to connect a series of DEMs in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, spatial-analyst

I have a set of 4 DEMs for a study area however they don't overlap they only meet at the edges.

How do I collate the 4 into 1 DEM raster that I can then use to convert into contours and slope representation?

Comment: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/mosaic.htm

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Mosaic to New Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/mosaic-to-new-raster.htm) tool in the Data Management toolbox.  This will accept your four DEMs as input and merge them together into one.

[image]

From there you will need the Spatial Analyst extension to create contours and calculate slope.

Answer (score 0):

Try using production contouring. You do need an extension for it, but if you have it this can be a viable option.

See here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//010300000068000000.htm